# Why has `android:screenOrientation="behind"` no effect in android 4.1.2?

Tags: android, android-activity, orientation, screen-orientation, android-orientation

As a test sample, there is an application with 2 activities: `MainActivity` that launches `SecondActivity` on button click.
It works fine on Android 4.0.4, but on Android 4.1.2 I encountered unexpected behaviour.

AutoRotation in system settings is off (or is on - it doesn't matter, "behind" option is ignored anyway).
`android:screenOrientation="landscape"` is set for `MainActivity` and `android:screenOrientation="behind"` is set for `SecondActivity`, which means that `SecondActivity` must be launched in landscape orientation too.
It's true for Android 4.0.4, but on Android 4.1.2 `SecondActivity` starts with portrait orientation.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.my.example.testbehindorientation.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.my.example.testbehindorientation.SecondActivity"
        android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_second"
        android:screenOrientation="behind" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

SecondActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    logOrientation("onCreate");
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    logOrientation("onDestroy");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    logOrientation("onResume");
}

private void logOrientation(String prefix) {
        int requestedOrientation = this.getRequestedOrientation();
        WindowManager lWindowManager =  (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Configuration cfg = getResources().getConfiguration();
        int lRotation = lWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();   
        int orientation = cfg.orientation;
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, prefix + ", requestedOrientation is " + requestedOrientation + ", rotation is " + lRotation + ", orientation is " + orientation);
}
```

Log output without `android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"` line in `AndroidManifest.xml` for `SecondActivity` after button click in `MainActivity`:

```
onCreate, requestedOrientation is 3, rotation is 1, orientation is 2
onResume, requestedOrientation is 3, rotation is 1, orientation is 2
onDestroy, requestedOrientation is 3, rotation is 0, orientation is 1
onCreate, requestedOrientation is 3, rotation is 0, orientation is 1
onResume, requestedOrientation is 3, rotation is 0, orientation is 1
```

Log with line `android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"` included in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
onCreate, requestedOrientation is 3, rotation is 1, orientation is 2
onResume, requestedOrientation is 3, rotation is 1, orientation is 2
```

No activity recreation now, but the result is always the same - `SecondActivity` is starting with portrait orientation! :(
That is, `SecondActivity` rotates to portrait after onResume for some reason.
Why?.

Tested on:

- Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 4.0.4 (Ok)
- Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 4.1.? (Bug)
- Emulator with Android 4.1.2 with portrait home screen orientation (Bug)
- Android 4.0.3 emulator (Ok)
- Android 4.2 emulator (Bug)

Comment: Do you have `onConfigurationChanged` handler with a call to `super`?

Comment: @Stan I can add `onConfigurationChanged` but it cannot help. It only lets me see the moment after `onResume` when it's called with new portrait orientation (if line `android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"` presents in AndroidManifest.xml)

Comment: There is an open bug report [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41730)

Comment: does it behave as expected when AutoRotation in system settings is **ON** ?

Comment: @forgivegod No, it doesn't. If auto-rotation is ON, SecondActivity ignores "behind" attribute and rotates with the phone screen.

Comment: @Irina: did this problem get solved?

Answer (score 0):

`android:targetSdkVersion="16"`

Remove this statement in your manifest file, because SDKVersion=16 is only available for v4.0.

Comment: SDKVersion = 16 stands for Android 4.1, by the way. Anyway, removing or keeping this statement cannot help.

Comment: Target sdk version is the version you build with.  Its completely allowed for it to be a different version than the device its run on.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing problem changing orientation using manifest you change the orientation in java. Here is complete code for manifest and activities.
**Manifest.xml**

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.my.example.testbehindorientation.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.my.example.testbehindorientation.SecondActivity"
        android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_second" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Second activity in landscape**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);            
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);//Change according to need this is for landscape
    logOrientation("onCreate");
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    logOrientation("onDestroy");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    logOrientation("onResume");
}

private void logOrientation(String prefix) {
        int requestedOrientation = this.getRequestedOrientation();
        WindowManager lWindowManager =  (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Configuration cfg = getResources().getConfiguration();
        int lRotation = lWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();   
        int orientation = cfg.orientation;
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, prefix + ", requestedOrientation is " + requestedOrientation + ", rotation is " + lRotation + ", orientation is " + orientation);
}
```

**Add the following code in *onCreate()* method of MainActivity**

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);//Change according to need this is for landscape
```